# Do diode SPICE model parameters affect each other?

Tags: diodes, simulation, spice

I was modifying a diode spice model to better fit the datasheet parameters (the breakdown voltage on datasheet was 85V, and the model went into breakdown at 65V). I noticed the junction capacitance went from 1.7pF, which was both within datasheet and exactly stated in the model itself (CJO = 1.72pF). After modifying the breakdown voltage the model's junction capacitance went up to 12pF, and lowering the CJO on the model didn't help. Is there any reason that these two parameters would interact with each other? The model is for a BAS116 diode.

Model in question as it's not large:

```
*SRC=BAS116;DI_BAS116;Diodes;Si;  60.0V  0.215A  3.00us   Diodes Inc.
Switching Diode
.MODEL DI_BAS116 D  ( IS=4.53u RS=0.383 BV=60.0 IBV=5.00n
+ CJO=1.72p  M=0.333 N=4.07 TT=4.32u )
```

Comment: What is the model? Built in? Is the model a circuit library or using the standard diode model?

Comment: Standard diode model, I'll actually paste it in the question in a second as it's only a few lines.

Comment: How are you using this model?

Comment: If you modify TT from 4.32u to the default of zero, do you *still* get a breakdown-voltage dependency of capacitance?

Comment: I'll try that in a second but for the previous comment (currently on mobile so I cant draw the circuit out but its simple) its effectively an RC series circuit, 1Meg resistor,  where I measure the rms voltage and current to determine reactance of the diode capacitance. Hooked up to a 1Mhz 0.5AC 5V DC sine wave.